# How can I make this for loop more efficient to avoid "out of memory crashes"?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, out-of-memory

resourcesNotGatheredString is a really long string. My debugger said 32000 characters. I need to traverse the whole thing. It holds the info from 5 "fields" a player plays on, including the x and y coords of certain cells they touched (resources). I need to add these coords to arrays. This for loop works perfectly for shorter strings, does exactly what I want. The field is input by the user. It works fine if the field is 1, but if it is anything higher, the page crashed. (It needs to be able to go up to 5). If I wanted to slice the string, I do not know ahead of times the indices where I would need to slice them. (I would need to slice at '#', but the position of it can vaey). I can't hardcode them in. I tried adding this into the loop but it wasn't working properly. Any other solution?

```
        var field_index = 1;
        for (j=0; j<resourcesNotGatheredString.length; j++) {

            if (resourcesNotGatheredString[j] == '#') {
                field_index += 1;
            }
            if (field_index != field){
                continue;
            }
            if (resourcesNotGatheredString[j] == '|' && field_index == field) {
                j += 1;
            }
            if (resourcesNotGatheredString[j] == 'x' && field_index == field) {
                x_string = ""
                j += 1;
                while (resourcesNotGatheredString[j] != 'y' && field_index == field) {
                    x_add = resourcesNotGatheredString[j];
                    x_string = x_string + x_add;
                    j += 1;
                }
                resourcesNotGatheredX.push(parseInt(x_string));
            }
            if (resourcesNotGatheredString[j] == 'y' && field_index == field) {
                y_string = "";
                j +=1;
                while (resourcesNotGatheredString[j] != '|' && field_index == field) {
                    y_add = resourcesNotGatheredString[j];
                    y_string = y_string + y_add;
                    j+=1;
                }
                
                resourcesNotGatheredY.push(parseInt(y_string));
            }
                
        }
```

Comment: 32KB is not "really long".

Comment: This code is hard to follow as it's not clear what the input data is, what it represents, nor what the desired outputs are.

Comment: after you `continue` when `field_index != field` ... since neither `field_index` nor `field` can change in the code after that, there's really no need to keep testing for `field_index == field` in every single condition - not the issue, just redundant

Comment: Can you supply a short piece of code to generate an input string which causes out of memory crashes?  Preferably as part of a code snippet readers can run to reproduce the problem.

Comment: `I would need to slice at '#'` so you can use yourLongString.split("#") to create an array of things between the #s.  Then, you can simplify your code to something that works on one chunk at a time.

Comment: The `while` loops are probably looping infinitely - they should, but don't, check for `j` reaching the length of `resourcesNotGatheredString`